# ¿Como puedo cambiar mi formato de JSON de una salida PHP?

Tags: php, android-studio, json, mysqli

estoy haciendo una aplicacion android y requiero el resultado de una consulta de MySQL con parametro LIKE, en formato JSON, pero me aparece asi:

```
[[{"ID":"1234","RAZONSOCIAL":"CORPORATIVO DE SERVICIOS CV"},{"ID":"45678","RAZONSOCIAL":"DHL GLOBAL CV"},{"ID":"22222","RAZONSOCIAL":"GLOBA DISTRIBUCIONES]]
```

y me da problemas con Android, esta es la consulta que hago en php

```
$cliente=$_REQUEST['razon'];
$cadena=strlen($cliente);

if ($cliente!=null and $cadena > 3){
    $cliente=strtoupper($cliente);
        //echo $texto;
    $datos=Array();
    $param="%".$cliente."%";
    $sql="SELECT ID, RAZONSOCIAL FROM clientes WHERE RAZONSOCIAL LIKE ".$param;
    $resultado= mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if (!$resultado){
    echo("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($resultado));
}else
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($resultado)){
        $datos[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode(array($datos));

}
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

¿Puede ayudarme a entender si estoy mal o si es un tipo de arreglo diferente? Estoy aplicandolo para Android Studio y de alli planeo pasarlo a un spinner.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: añade por favor que errores son los que obtienes con lo que estas tratando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontre la respuesta, sucede que esta busqueda en particular estaba arrojando el resultado y se convertia en stdClass Object, asi que habia que convertir y reconvertir
asi quedo el codigo

```
$cliente=$_REQUEST['razon'];
$cadena=strlen($cliente);

if ($cliente!=null and $cadena > 3){
    $cliente=strtoupper($cliente);
    $datos=Array();
    $param="%".$cliente."%";
    $sql="SELECT ID, RAZONSOCIAL FROM clientes WHERE RAZONSOCIAL LIKE ".$param;
    $resultado= mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($resultado)){
      array_push($datos,$row);
    }
    $array2=json_decode(json_encode($datos),True);
    echo json_encode($array2);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Seguro que esa consulta no tiene error de sintaxis?, yo veo una falla en donde usas `LIKE`

Comment: tenias razón pero fue cuando comparti aqui el codigo, ya todo esta bien, muchas gracias por la observacion

Answer (score 0):

> Usa array_push
>   Además estas metiendo un array dentro de otro array.
>   Prueba con eso:

```
$cliente=$_REQUEST['razon'];
$cadena=strlen($cliente);

if ($cliente!=null and $cadena > 3){
    $cliente=strtoupper($cliente);
        //echo $texto;
    $datos=Array();
    $param="%".$cliente."%";
    $sql="SELECT ID, RAZONSOCIAL FROM clientes WHERE RAZONSOCIAL LIKE ".$param;
    $resultado= mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if (!$resultado){
    echo("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($resultado));
}else
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($resultado)){
       array_push($datos,$row);
    }
    echo json_encode($datos);

}
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```